# How to get logs from multiple detached commands on an already running Docker container

Tags: docker

I can use `docker exec -d CONTAINER_NAME sh -c "COMMAND"` to make a **running** container execute multiple concurrent commands.

However, when I run `docker logs CONTAINER_NAME` I only get the logs from the container's initial process.

How do I see the logs from COMMAND?

Comment: Just redirect command’s output to the stdout.

Comment: Does that have to be done when the command is launched?

Comment: Even if I do `docker exec -itd CONTAINER_NAME sh -c "yes >&1"`, I still don't see output because it's detatched.

Comment: `docker logs` output only captures the stdout and stderr of the main container process (pid 1) and so you need to redirect to `>/proc/1/fd/1`.  I'd avoid trying to script `docker exec`, though: think of a container more as packaging around a single process here, and it doesn't really make sense to get a shell on _e.g._ your nginx server.